# convert a date string using PHP

Tags: php, date

I need to convert a date string in a format like bellow using PHP,

```
2015-07-30T08:05:00.917Z
```

I try to convert using the bellow code,

```
echo str_replace('+00:00', '.917Z', gmdate('c', strtotime('2016-04-05 00:00:00')));
```

This will create  `2016-04-05T00:00:00.917Z` This is not correct,Is there any function to create date like this format?

Comment: `echo (new DateTime('2016-04-05 00:00:00'))->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.917\Z');`

Comment: `.917` is the number of milliseconds the the date you posted. Your input date doesn't contain information about milliseconds, you should not add `.917` to it but either append `.000` or use a function that supports milliseconds ([`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php))

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to create date from String.

```
1. date_create_from_format
   $date=date_create_from_format("DATE_FORMAT",$dateString);

2. $date=new DateTime();
   $date=$date->createFromFormat("DATE_FORMAT", $dateString);
```

Using following link to get your DATE_FORMAT.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as @Alok has mentioned in his answer.
Or similarly using the following code.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(TRUE));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z');
```

Note that the microsecond mentioned in your question is of 3 digits. But generally php date formatting outputs microseconds in 6 digits precision.

Like the above code outputs  *`2016-04-06T09:24:50.830000Z`*

So I think you have to do some hack there if the digit precision is important.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it through the function formatTime. This creates a new DateTime object in PHP called $date that can also easily be manipulated if you need. The examples below formats the date in two different ways, both work.

**Procedural Style:**

```
function formatTime($millis) { 
        $date = new DateTime($millis); 
        return date_format($date, 'l, jS F Y \a\t g:ia'); 
}
```

**Object Oriented Style:**

```
function formatTime($millis) { 
        $date = new DateTime($millis); 
        return $date->format('l, jS F Y \a\t g:ia'); 
}
```

The format for date can be found at this link: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Hope this helps.